# Go net listener closing and routine handling

Tags: http, go, proxy, goroutine

I am starting a routine and listening on a net listener (HTTP). I want to close the listener, close the routine and start a new routine, and restart the listener. When I close the listener all hell breaks loose.

(`listener` is global)

```
listener, _ = net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)
go PassThrough()
```

where

```
func PassThrough() {
    verbose := flag.Bool("v", false, "should every proxy request be logged to stdout")
    flag.Parse()
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.Verbose = *verbose
    log.Fatal(http.Serve(listener, proxy))
}
```

So this works but if I want to stop passThrough() and re apply the listener to a different task (for instance a different proxy "job") closing the listener with `listener.Close()` causes it to break when I then try to re Listen and call a new go routine.

I get the error:

```
ProxyControllers.go:146: accept tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: use of closed network connection
reverseproxy.go:141: http: proxy error: EOF
```

When I then try to reuse the Listener.

I think I need to tell the routine to close itself down somehow when i Close() the listener?

Im using the [goproxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) library

Comment: You can't re-use a listener, you need to "Listen" again.

Answer (score 1):

1. Flags should only be parsed once and probably in an `init` func.
2. You can't reuse a listener, you will have to call `Listen` again.
3. Don't call `log.Fatal`, that will terminate your program.

Example:

```
var verbose = flag.Bool("v", false, "should every proxy request be logged to stdout")

func runProxy(typ, host, port string) (listener tcp.Listener) {
    listener, _ = net.Listen(typ, host+":"+port)
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.Verbose = *verbose

    go http.Serve(listener, proxy) // you can probably ignore this error
    return
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    l := runProxy(....)
    //do something
    l.Close()
    l = runProxy(....)
    //....
}
```